# Input value inside an innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
function createJSON() {
    var data = new Object();
    $("input[class = detail_text]").each(function() {
        data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
    console.log(jsonString);
}
```

I am trying to get the value of input in an innerHTML. This input fields are multi valued. 
How to get these attributes? In my code, the last one is the only one that get save. I am new to this. Thanks.

```
<div class="window task" style="left: 120px; top:200px; display:none;" data-nodetype="task" id="taskcontainer0">
        <div class="ctrl_container">
            <div class="button_remove">x</div>
        </div>
        <div class="details_container">
            <label class="detail_label">Name</label>
            <input type = "text" class="detail_text" name = "task"/><br/>
            <label class = "detail_label">Description</label>
            <input type = "text" class ="detail_text" name = "msg">
        </div>
        </div>
```

This is the html code.

Comment: Please provide the HTML code also. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fields are multi-valued, you probably want to store arrays for each name, see inline comments:

```
function createJSON() {
    var data = {}; // {} is usually better than new Object

    $("input[class = detail_text]").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            name = $this.attr("name");

        // Is there already a value saved for this name?
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            // No, create a blank array
            data[name] = [];
        }

        // Add this value to the array of values for this name
        data[name].push($this.val());
    });

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

    console.log(jsonString);

}
```

Also note that you probably meant to do the `JSON.stringify` *after* the loop.

Or if you only want an array *if* you have multiple values for a given `name`, then:

```
function createJSON() {
    var data = {}; // {} is usually better than new Object

    $("input[class = detail_text]").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            name = $this.attr("name");

        // Is there already a value saved for this name?
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            // No, save this value
            data[name] = $this.val();
        }
        else {
            // Yes, is it an array?
            if (!Array.isArray(data[name])) {
                // No, make it one
                data[name] = [data[name]]; // Wraps the existing value in an array
            }

            // Add this value to it
            data[name].push($this.val());
        }
    });

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

    console.log(jsonString);

}
```

`Array.isArray` is an ES5 thing, but the shim is trivial:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = (function() {
        var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

        return function(arg) {
            return toString.call(arg) === "[object Array]";
        };
    })();
}
```

---

Side note: You almost never want to use an attribute selector (`"input[class = detail_text]"`) for selecting by class, because of course elements can have multiple classes. Instead, use a class selector: `"input.detail_text"`

Comment: The first value is null. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @jihyo: With the code above, the first value *can't* be `null`; `.val()` never returns `null`, it always returns either a string (if the jQuery object has at least one element in it and that element is a form field) or `undefined` (if not). It could be `"null"` if you have that actual text in a field. Here's both of the above: http://jsbin.com/yafaw/1, http://jsbin.com/yafaw/2